# Looking for a reflection of 30° at a line

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I'm trying to find a matrix-expression of a 30° reflection at the line $g(x)=2x+4$

Somebody can give a hint?

Greetings

Comment: Do you mean rotation of the line by $30^\circ$?

Comment: What is a $30^\circ$ reflection? The best interpretation I can come up with still leaves two possibilities.

Comment: Sorry for the bad english. With reflection I mean http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(mathematics)#Reflection_across_a_line_in_the_plane and a reflection of 30° means, that g and the $x_1$-Axis intersect with 30°. Sorry again for the bad english :-(